# Determining a probability function for a sum of N i.i.d. geometric distributions between where N is discrete with a geometric pf

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions, geometric-probability

I was completing revision for an upcoming task and this question was presented. Was hoping for some insight!

*The random variable $N$ is discrete, with probability function*
$$f_N(n)=\begin{cases}
p(1-p)^{n-1},  & \text{; n = 1, ...} \\
0, & \text{; otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$
*where $0 < p < 1$. The random variables $X_1, X_2, ...$ are independent of $N$ and are independent and identically distributed with probability function*
$$f_X(k)=\begin{cases}
r(1-r)^{k-1},  & \text{; k = 1, ...} \\
0, & \text{; otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$
*where $0<r<1$. Find the probability generating function of*
$$S_N=\sum_{j=1}^N X_j$$
*and hence determine the probability function of $S_N$.*

Any help is greatly appreciated! I can derive the moment-generating-function just fine but need some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: $Ez^{S_N}=E[E(z^{S_N}|N)]$.

Comment: You want the probability generating function  rather than the  moment generating function.  What did you derive?

Comment: @Daniel, Can you add context so your question can be reopened? What did you find?

Comment: @YuvalPeres The relevant context would be - Background: University homework, Motivation: Understanding and application of compound probability distributions, Relevant Definitions would be the one detailed in geetha290krm 's comment, Current progress at time of posting was nil, however I have now completed it. Is it beneficial to post my own answer? I've not much experience on actually asking questions on StackExchange. I apologise for the lack of context and appreciate all the responses!

Answer (score 2):

You repeatedly toss two coins with heads probability $r$ and $p$ respectively, until the first coin yields heads. Then, you examine  the second coin. If it also yields heads you stop, otherwise start over.
Thus the probability function of $S_N$ is geometric with parameter $pr$, that is,
$$P(S_N=s)=pr(1-pr)^{s-1} \,.$$